# WooCommerce admin order page - remove hyperlink on email and phone

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I have tried to remove the hyperlinks on phone and email on WooCommerce admin order page by adding code to `functions.php`

There I added the following code

```php
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_order_item_permalink' , '__return_false' );
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Someone who can help me with this?

---

See attached print screen for clarity:

[image: printsreen]

Comment: The hook `woocommerce_order_item_permalink`is not for backend and has no effect on email address and phone… Note that address and phone are not saved as order meta data, but not order item meta data…

Comment: ok, thx -  I see if I can figure out how to do it another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php) we find on lines [345-347](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php#L345-L347) for `billing_phone`

```php
if ( 'billing_phone' === $field_name ) {
    $field_value = wc_make_phone_clickable( $field_value );
}
```

`wc_make_phone_clickable()` refers to [includes/wc-core-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/ed1a59b39bf5ee16d356f3a1654bce8c6a502602/includes/wc-core-functions.php) lines [2155-2159](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/ed1a59b39bf5ee16d356f3a1654bce8c6a502602/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L2155-L2159)

```php
function wc_make_phone_clickable( $phone ) {
    $number = trim( preg_replace( '/[^\d|\+]/', '', $phone ) );

    return $number ? '<a href="tel:' . esc_attr( $number ) . '">' . esc_html( $phone ) . '</a>' : '';
}
```

---

So there is not immediately a filter to adjust this, so you could use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) instead.

```php
function action_admin_footer () {
    global $pagenow;
    
    // Only on order edit page
    if ( $pagenow != 'post.php' || get_post_type( $_GET['post'] ) != 'shop_order' ) return;

    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
        $( '#order_data .address a' ).each( function() {
            $( this ).replaceWith( $( this ).text() );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'action_admin_footer', 10, 0 );
```